# Multiple api contoller classes in one cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

**Question**

Is it possible to have multiple controllers in one file?

**Example**

The controller file `TestController.cs` located in the `Controllers` folder:

*TestController.cs*

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v2")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
     // action methods here...
}

[RoutePrefix("api/v1")]
public class OldTestController " ApiController
{
    // all action methods return an error stating that 
    // the user should update their client to be compatible with 
    // verison 2 of the API.
}
```

- `GET api/v2/Test` will return data.
- `GET api/v1/Test` will return error message.

**Description**

I made a Version 2 of my Rest API which includes breaking changes for the older mobile application.

I want the old routes to show an json error message to the user to update their mobile app.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: yes, you can have more than one class (controller) on the same file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no limits to how many Controllers you can have in a file.

For marking a controller as obsolete one option would be to implement an ActionFilter to return the error you want.

```
public class ObsoleteApiAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Update your app");
        actionContext.Response = response;
    }
}
```

Then just apply to the controller or method on which you would like to return the error.

```
[ObsoleteApi]
[RoutePrefix("api/v1")]
public class OldTestController : ApiController
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: The main question is if I can have both of these controllers in the same file?